# Image viewpager inside listview not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I know this question has been asked many times, and I have looked everyone of them here but none of which helped me.

What I am trying to do is to mimic the UI from iOS where you have a UITableView with cells that are UICollectionView. The cells are images that page horizontally. I am trying to do this with a listview of viewpagers.

My current solution is I create each row before hand. It is a linearlayout with a title, the viewpager, and two buttons on the bottom. I already created the adapters for the viewpagers as well. In the getView method of listview, I just return the view in the created collection based on the position as the index. I know this is bad practice, it uses a lot of memory, but the method is just one line.

I have tried the viewholder pattern, but only some rows in the listview will get the viewpager. The recycling mechanism doesn't really help in my situation, so I sacrifice more memory for the same effect.

So I can  see all the viewpagers in my listview. The problem now is that only the bottom 2 are able to page from iamge to image. The ones on position 0,1,2, couldn't. I thought it has to do with listview intercepting the events, but how come the ones on the bottom work perfectly??

Any help is appreciated!